# カラムのデフォルト値が「なし」について

Tags: mysql

**最終的にやりたいこと**
NULLを除いて、「デフォルト値なし」のカラムのみ抽出したい

---

**Q1.phpMyAdminで「デフォルト値なし」と表示されるカラムがあるのですが、どういう意味ですか？ 「デフォルト値なし」が内部的にどう処理されているかを知りたいです。**

下記コマンド実行したら、「NOT NULLで デフォルト値なし」のカラムは「Default NULL」と表示されました。

```
show columns from テーブル名;
```

> Default フィールドは、このカラムに割り当てられているデフォルト値を示します。このカラムの明示的なデフォルト値が NULL
>   である場合や、カラム定義に DEFAULT 句が含まれていない場合、これは NULL です。

[SHOW COLUMNS 構文](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/show-columns.html)

「カラム定義に DEFAULT 句が含まれていない場合、これは NULL です」の意味は、下記何れですか？

- デフォルト値なしとNULLの意味は同じ
- デフォルト値なしとNULLの意味は異なるが、SHOW COLUMNS 実行結果としては同じ

---

**Q2.カラムに対して「NOT NULLで デフォルト値ありなし」と「NOT NULL制約を設定しているかどうか」の情報はどこにありますか？**
`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`にあるのかと思い下記SQLを試してみましたが、よくわかりませんでした

```
select * from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` where `TABLE_SCHEMA`='テーブル名'
```

Answer (score 1):

おそらくですが、 MySQL 側では、「デフォルト値が NULL」であることと、「デフォルト値が指定されていないこと」は等価であると思っています。

> Q2. カラムに対して「NOT NULLで デフォルト値ありなし」と「NOT NULL制約を設定しているかどうか」の情報はどこにありますか？

```
select IS_NULLABLE,  COLUMN_DEFAULT from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'テーブル名';
```

がそれぞれ、「NULL が許可されているか」と「カラムのデフォルト値」を表します。つまり、「NOT NULLである」とは、 `IS_NULLABLE` が `NO` であることです。